# Adding jQuery Plugin (owl carousel) via Yarn to Rails 6 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hadoop-yarn, owl-carousel, ruby-on-rails-6

I am still a little confused with the new way to handle jQuery Plugins in Rails 6. In Rails 5 I simply added the files to my libs folder and required them in the css and js files.

Now I am trying to make the Owl Carousel to work with Yarn. My Rails 6 project has already bootstrap and jquery working (flatpickr is working fine).

```
yarn add owl.carousel2
```

In application.js

```
import 'owl.carousel2/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel2'
```

webpack environment

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

Application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Error:

> TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try to change on your application.js:

```
import 'owl.carousel2/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel2'
```

To:

```
import owlCarousel from "owl.carousel2";
import "owl.carousel2/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
```

At my project, this exported the `owlCarousel` function and made the message `TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function` disappear.